# What is a term to describe something that is not necessary to begin with, but becomes so as a result of a non necessary choice?

Tags: terminology

So basically, you have three different types of 'things' (for lack of a better term): You have that which is necessary, that which is contingent (you have a choice), and that which is necessary but only because it must be so after a contingent choice has been made. So it's necessary, but not to begin with, and is necessary in a very different way. I guess you could call that which was necessary to begin with, necessarily necessary, and that which is necessary by choice, not necessarily necessary. But of course, am sure there's a better word, or at least term, to describe this phenomenon.

Comment: You might consider [***concomitant**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/concomitant) contingencies* (the collocation [has been used before](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22concomitant+contingencies%22)). But *contingencies* aren't always a matter of choice - in fact, they're usually just "unforeseen" things that might or might not arise (by *chance*, not *choice*).

Comment: This needs context. "`Terminology` is a system of terms belonging or peculiar to a science, art, or specialized subject, nomenclature." If you just mean in general, it needs the SWR tag and an example usage. There's only two types: (un)necessary. Which one it is will be [*contingent*](https://www.google.com/search?q=contingent&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) on your context. Most of the answers so far are either synonyms of *contingent* or assume a specific context, i.e, medicine.

Comment: Can you edit in an example?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One of the senses of **entailment** applies:

> entailment
>
> ...
>
> 2. something involved as a necessary part or consequence of something:
>
> Long hours of work are an entailment of the job.

[[Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/entailment)]

Comment: I nearly always hear this used in the form of "[the choice of] X *entails* Y".

Comment: Ah yes, entailment. I've come across this term before in my studies of logic, but I forgot it's exact meaning. Now that you've mentioned it here, it seems like a near perfect match for what am looking for.

Answer (score 10):

That (originally unnecessary) *thing* has now become necessary because it is ***incidental to*** the other activity (choice that you made).

ODO:

> **[incidental](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/incidental)**
> *ADJECTIVE*
>
> **2** (**incidental to**) Happening as a result of (an activity):
>
> ‘the ordinary risks incidental to a fireman's job’
>
> ‘For instance, a charity has to refrain from political advocacy,
> unless such lobbying activity is merely incidental to the charitable
> purpose.’

Comment: And what's the downvoter's problem with this answer? Really surprising!

Comment: Not a downvoter, but to me, "incidental" does not imply that the thing in question is required, only that it is related. A requirement is something that MUST be present. An incidental thing is more like a side-effect.

Answer (score 2):

If thing A is not an inherent requirement for an overall process P, but is a requirement if you choose to implement thing B, then A is a **[requisite](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/requisite)** for B.

A requisite is something required to achieve a desired goal or comply with something else. For example, if you work at Joe's pizza emporium, you can make pies, but if you want to deliver the pizzas, you need a driver's license. Having a valid driver's license is a direct requisite for being a Joe's delivery driver. Furthermore, having a valid license requires having a certain level of car insurance, so having that insurance is an indirect requisite for delivering Joe's pizzas.

Answer (score 1):

A possible future condition, indirect effect or result of something (e.g. a choice) is an **implication**.

> Definition:  something implied; a close connection.
>
> Example: *The newspapers discussed the implications of the president's election*.

Answer (score 1):

How about *logical necessity* or *modus ponens*?

Google search:

> [*logical
>   necessity*](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=logical+necessity&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8):
>   that state of things that obliges something to be as it is because no
>   alternative is logically possible; a thing that logically must be so
>
> [*modus
>   ponens*](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=modus+poenes&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8):
>   the rule of logic stating that if a conditional statement (“if p then
>   q ”) is accepted, and the antecedent (p) holds, then the consequent
>   (q) may be inferred

In the context of your question, all this means is that if A is a choice, and if A being chosen implies that B is necessarily true, then the consequence B is a necessary result of the choice A.

Answer (score 1):

LATENT

Fuel, as gasoil or gasoline or alcohol, has heat latent energy waiting for pressure or spark to start.
Some people in special situations their true personalities or talents show up, that personality or that talent was in a latent state.

From [Merriam Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/latent):

> present and capable of emerging or developing but not now visible, obvious, active, or symptomatic

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your specific meaning, here's two phrases that may or may not apply:

"Mission creep" -- a military term referring to the inevitable broadening of the scope of the initial mission once boots are on the ground.

"Inheritable error" -- you want to go to the store to buy milk, but you can't find your key, then you realize your husband accidentally took your keys with him that morning so you go to call him, but your phone is out of battery, so you go to charge it, but you find your dog has chewed on your charger and destroyed it, and in doing so broke a tooth, so now you have to, by necessity, a) go to the vet, b) buy a new cell phone charger, c) charge your phone, d) divorce your husband... e) and you still haven't gotten any milk.

Answer (score 0):

Your description the mechanism by which the the thing becomes necessary is very vague. However if the choice that led to the thing becoming necessary was the very choice to actually use the thing in the first place, the term **addictive** comes to mind.